# Dynamic layout and buttons in my existing layout after the image animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to load my dynamic layout and buttons in my existing layout after the image animation. Actually my image has to move from center to the top of the screen. after that my dynamic layout with button as to visible below the image. but my dynamic layout and button is not visible.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgm2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/jpa2" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:max="100"/>
```

**translate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <translate

    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-26%p"
    android:duration="3000"


    />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar probar;
int progress=0;
Handler h = new Handler();
ImageView logoview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    logoview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    probar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            while(progress <100){
                progress+=10;

                h.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        probar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                });
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    probar.setVisibility(1500);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }   


        }


    }).start();


    logoview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Animation animation =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.animator.translate);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    logoview.startAnimation(animation);

    LinearLayout ll =new LinearLayout(this);
    ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    LinearLayout hl =new LinearLayout(this);
    hl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    hl.setLayoutParams(lp);
    hl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ll.addView(hl);


    Button bigdata =new Button(this);
    bigdata.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.data);
    hl.addView(bigdata);

    Button cloud = new Button(this);
    cloud.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cloud);
    hl.addView(cloud);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your translate animation with the following:

```
<translate
android:fromYDelta="50%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="3000"
/>
```

Feel free to revert if this doesn't work.

To make the layout appear after the animation, modify your Handler as follows:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          LinearLayout ll =new LinearLayout(this);
          ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
          LinearLayout hl =new LinearLayout(this);
          hl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =new          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          hl.setLayoutParams(lp);
          hl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          ll.addView(hl);    
      }
  }, 3100);
```

Comment: The layout is visible now but my idea is to load the layout and button after the animation is done. now layout and button loaded before the animation.